# SSL redirect on EC2 instance behind SSL terminating load balancer

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm trying to redirect all url's to https in a web application.

I have an ec2 instance behind an elastic load balancer.  SSL is terminated on the load balancer.

Any attempts at redirection end up giving me the familiar 'this page is requesting in a way which will never complete'.

The load balancer forwards 443 and 80 to port 80 on the instance.

This is what I have in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{X-FORWARDED-PROTO} !=on  
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?  Kind thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

untested.. but I try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-proto

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much.  Been struggling with this for a while now.  Much appreciated.  Please upvote this is answer if you find this a help.  Thank you...

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Solution still works. Some explanation could be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-proto

Comment: Worked for me. Tested today

Answer (score 0):

[Mike](https://serverfault.com/users/23818/mike)'s answer is mostly correct, but it's important to point out that the load balancer will still need to carryout its health check routine to ensure that the ec2 instance is still alive and well. This can be done with an additional `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/alive\.html$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

...where `alive.html` is the name of your health check file.